# How can I make my slideshow auto play?

Tags: java, css, slideshow

On [my homepage](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com), I have a slideshow that im trying to have it autoplay upon load with a nice fade transition. I turned off the auto play feature because the fade is to fast. I added this for the transition (which is choppy).  Its a template site from squarespace. I do have an option to add java into a "page code injection" area.

```
.slide {    
-webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;}
```

Comment: [This](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/#.UhZokxW6bIU) might help you.

Comment: currently it only changes on click. i want it to auto play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason firebug won't let me open up the console panel. The best solution would be to edit the JS to autoplay. In case that can't be done, you could auto trigger your own click event on the `div`s using jQuery

```
    <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.setInterval(slideClick, 5000);

    function slideClick() {
     $(".slide").click();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: this puts it up in the left corner of my screen as text

Comment: You need to inclucd it below you jQuery library include and the wrap it in script tags. I'll edit my answer to show you

Comment: if you copy and paste this code just before your `</head>` tag, it should work fine.